# IOS storyboard - how to place visual elements on a storyboard screen

Tags: ios, ios5, storyboard

[image]I set up a storyboard with some screens. I was able to put the headings on the different screens, but for some reason I can not figure out how to place the buttons and textfields on the screen.

How do I navigate to those options in the right side of the screen?

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're zoomed in to 100%. When you're zoomed out, you can't add controls to the view controller.

Edit: Since you're zoomed in, are you using the control library ([on the right panel view, at the bottom](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html))? Just drag buttons or fields from there onto your view.

Edit 2: as Alladinian noticed, you had entered search text on your control list, which is why not everything was visible.

Comment: I am 100% zoomed in, but I don't see how to change the buttons/labels.  I am able to change the background color, but thats it.

Comment: Right....the weird thing is that I don't see the buttons/labels to drag. I'll post my screen shot.

Comment: @Genadinik Just click the third (cube) icon on the bottom right inspector pane...

Comment: @Alladinian i did, but it doesn't show the buttons. The options it shows is the ListView, TableView, etc.

Comment: Click here: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s199/sh/ce39c78a-d89e-40a3-a88e-7418834d2ea3/214cb2f4c6e9efabfee6c400a3315960 ... you can then scroll down the list. Remember that in Lion you don't get visible scroll bars. You can also type in the search box below to quickly find what you want.

Comment: @TimSullivan I think the problem is that I don't have ios as an option in the dropdown there on the bottom right. Would you know how to get the ios option to appear there like you have on your screen shot?

Comment: @Genadinik It is _your_ screenshot... Tim just pointed out the icon you have to click on...

Comment: @Alladinian and TimSullivan I just put a second screen shot to show how it looks for me when you click on the 3rd icon there on bottom right. Thanks for your patience guys.

Comment: @TimSullivan Just added a screen shot to show what I have under that 3rd screen.

Comment: @Genadinik Just delete 'viewc' from the search bar. You are filtering based on this string and that's why you do not see any other elements (just view controllers)

Comment: @Alladinian omg that did it!!!! :) Thank you very much.  Didn't even notice that stuff was there - drove myself totally nuts :) You helped me quite a bit! Thanks again!